# Parse Json array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

```
  var array=  [
    {"Name":"Test", "Status":{"Id":100, "Alias":"A"}},
    {"Name":"Test2", "Status":{"Id":101, "Alias":"B"}},
    {"Name":"Test3", "Status":{"Id":102, "Alias":"C"}}
    ];
```

How to loop throw value of array of Name and Id in JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
array.forEach(item => console.log(item.Name))

array.forEach(item => console.log(item.Status.Id))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use array as variable so replace to `arr` and try following,

```js
var arr =  [
    {"Name":"Test", "Status":{"Id":100, "Alias":"A"}},
    {"Name":"Test2", "Status":{"Id":101, "Alias":"B"}},
    {"Name":"Test3", "Status":{"Id":102, "Alias":"C"}}
    ];
arr.forEach(function(item){
  console.log('Name: ' + item.Name);
  console.log('Status Id: ' + item.Status.Id);
  console.log('Status Alias: ' + item.Status.Alias);
});
```